# Traversing a Python object tree

Tags: python, reload, traversal

I'm trying to implement dynamic reloading objects in Python, that reflect code changes live.

Modules reloading is working, but I have to recreate every instance of the modules' classes for changes to become effective.

The problem is that objects data (objects `__dict__` content) is lost during the process.

So I tried another approach:

```
def refresh(obj, memo=None):
    if memo is None:
        memo = {}
    d = id(obj)
    if d in memo:
        return
    memo[d] = None
    try:
        obj.__class__ = getattr(sys.modules[obj.__class__.__module__], 
                obj.__class__.__name__)
    except TypeError:
        return
    for item in obj.__dict__.itervalues():
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            for k, v in item.iteritems():
                refresh(k, memo)
                refresh(v, memo)
        elif isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
            for v in item:
                refresh(v, memo)
        else:
            refresh(item, memo)
```

And surprisingly it works ! After calling refresh() on my objects, the new code becomes effective, without need to recreate them.

But I'm not sure if this is the correct way to traverse an object ? Is there a better way to traverse an object's components ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/160164/) in the Python Cookbook (or maybe even better its version in the "printed" one, which I believe you can actually read for free with google book search, or for sure on O'Reilly's "Safari" site using a free 1-week trial subscription -- I did a lot of editing on Hudson's original recipe to get the "printed book" version!).

Comment: This is very similar to the solution I adopted (some "top level" classes are wrapped and track their instances to allow reloading them). The problem is that I don't want to wrap all the classes in my package (or inherit from a reloading class as in your example), just the top level ones. This is why I need an object tree traversing function.

Comment: I believe you cannot do it with complete generality -- depending on e.g. __slots__ and other metaclass functionality, Python objects may be coded to simply not support that (that's why specific support is needed, when you code extensions, for garbage-collection traversals, weakrefs, pickling/unpickling, &c). Open files, DB connections, generator objects, locks, ... If you're willing to risk missing some parts, make sure at least you cover sets, deques, default_factory members of defaultdicts, etc, etc.

Comment: Ok then I just have to add more type tests in my iterations switch. It would be nice to have some kind of has_sequence_interface/has_mapping_interface() functions to test the way an object can be iterated.